# Firefox 3.6 required inputs

Tags: javascript, html, firefox3.6, polyfills, mozilla-prism

I'm trying to find a shim which will stop Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 (under Prism) to stop submitting a form when the input is set to `required`.

I've just tried using [Afarkas's webshim](http://github.com/afarkas/webshim) but that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the Web Forms polyfills on the Modernizr list.

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

This one appears to do the trick: http://ericleads.com/h5validate/

Comment: That seems to only highlight that it's required, not stop on submit?

Comment: It looks like it fires events you can handle, according to the wiki. Really, this would be easy to put together yourself via jQuery with a submit handler.